# What is the origin of the phrase "buck naked"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang, dialects, eggcorn

The phrase *buck naked* is well known and means "completely naked". It is synonymous to *butt naked* and *stark naked*, both self-explanatory. However, there are a few confusing aspects to the etymology of *buck naked*.

My research brought me across a few plausible explanations:

1. The word "buck" comes from [buckskin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buckskin), which is a deer/horse like animal.
2. A slang term used by Americans against natives (Indians) for young males who often fought or hunted without clothing.
3. It is a [Bowdlerization](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bowdlerize) of "butt naked" so that it can be used in public without causing unnecessary discomfort. A euphemism of some sort.

All three explanations seemed equally possible to me, and I failed to unearth an authoritative source to confirm any of them.

It would also be interesting to know if the phrase is more popular in some parts of the world than others.

Comment: I've never heard of "buck naked" only "butt naked". (England)

Comment: @Nick you should [visit ELU more often](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/which-is-correct-buck-naked-or-butt-naked).

Comment: @Nick "butt naked" is found either as an eggcorn or deliberate increase in vulgarity, but "buck naked" is well-attested in England.

Comment: @RegDwighт: Surely this is a duplicate of [Which is correct, “buck naked” or “butt naked”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/which-is-correct-buck-naked-or-butt-naked). I recalled this having come up on ELU before, but because your comment didn't make it clear (and I didn't follow your link), I had to search for it myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers while the matter of the phrase's origin was included as a point that "would be of interest" in that question, it was neither the crux of that question, nor addressed by the answers.

Comment: @Jon: If we allowed every *"Which is correct?"* question to have a separate *"Which came first?"* version, that would just be pointless proliferation. I think you should have voted to close this one, and posted your answer against the original.

Comment: I am amazed to how people consider a question about the _correct_ usage of a phrase and a question regarding the _etymology_ of a phrase to be _one and the same_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A "pointless proliferation" you say, I call it segregation. The question [Which is correct, “buck naked” or “butt naked”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/which-is-correct-buck-naked-or-butt-naked) is for those who are seeking which expression is appropriate, I on the other hand am seeking the origin of the expression "buck naked" used to convey _absolute nudity_. I am sure these are two different aspects, otherwise each _word-choice_ question would also unexceptionally cover etymology as well!

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: I realise it's possible to distinguish several different "sub-questions" in a case like this. As it happens, neither yours nor the original question actually ask what the expression *means*, for example. But taking things to your level, we'd presumably have to accept that as a "different" question if someone had asked it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My friend m sure that "different" question would be closed as a _General Reference_. But in all seriousness, I would like to  point out that while the meaning and such have been discussed in the answers to the alleged duplicate, their have been no indication towards its origin. Having said that I also disagree with your suggestion to re-post answers here to the _original_ question, as it would start a dangerous trend of answers obtuse to the OP's question.

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: Perhaps a mod will "merge" the two questions *and* the answers. You yourself have asked *if the phrase is more popular in some parts of the world than others*, which I'm tempted to assume means *more popular than **butt naked***, since any given speaker will normally only use one or the other. And let's face it - for an idiomatic usage, what does "correct" mean, other than "more popular"? Anyway, the original did ask about origin, and at least half-a-dozen comments/answers said that the origin was "uncertain", so you've gained nothing by explicitly asking it again.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Am afraid you have jumped to a conclusion there. What I meant by `more popular than others` is if the phrase is unheard in some parts of the world, which I consider may shed some light on its place of origin.

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: I think that's all settled by the earlier question. It started in North America (in the 20s or earlier) where they called "savage" young male Indians *bucks*. *Butt-naked* is a much later "eggcorn" that would also doubtless be American, since they use that word more than other Anglophones. Have a look at [Common Errors in English Usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contemporary+butt+naked+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: I did not hear the term "butt naked" until I may bed to Florida. They do not care how it was up north and they claim butt naked is correct. - they never heard of buck naked

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I notice that the book you linked to does not appear to give any references, or even discussion: it just makes assertion. Given the amount of ignorant assertions around in this area, why should we trust it?

Comment: @Colin: Well, you don't *have* to agree, obviously. But so far as I'm concerned, the answers to the "original" question had already established beyond reasonable doubt that ***buck** naked* came first (which seems to be the position of both upvoted answers here as well). I'd have thought that in the circumstances, the citation from [Paul Brians](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Paul-Brians/e/B001HPI8T2) that I linked to would count as an "authoritative reference" in and of itself. Are you saying you think ***butt*** came first and/or is "more correct"? No-one else seems to be defending that position.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/601898).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The possibility you left out is that, rather than a bowdlerisation of "butt naked," it was an eggcorn of it; however, determining whether such a change was deliberate or accidental would be nigh on impossible.

Of the three, we can argue in favour of the second, though with the people referenced being as much those of African as of American origin.

We find "buck naked" in the 19th Century.

We do not find "butt naked" during that period.

We do not find it any earlier.

We do find "buck" being used to refer to men of African and of American Indian origin.

We do find the lack of clothing in some parts of Africa and America remarked upon. We also find slaves in the American South often working with little clothing. (We also find it overstated, a cartoon of an African might likely feature them as naked even if that would be highly unlikely in the scenario depicted — we're talking about people with some pretty strong racial prejudices here).

As such, we have a group of people being called "bucks" whose nakedness is often remarked upon. This suggests that the likelihood of it being the origin is quite high.

It's far from conclusive though, and you aren't going to get any better unless you hit documents from the period and manage to track it down better yourself.

Comment: Does *butt* as a shortening of *buttocks* even go back that far?  It sounds 20th century to me.

Comment: @NateEldredge Late Middle English had both *butt* and *buttok*.

Comment: I think we can positively rule out "buck naked" being an eggcorn/bowlderization of "butt naked" if we can establish that the former out-dates the later. Do you have any reference on that matter?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Not necessarily. *Butt* is considered mildly offensive by some, and since people are generally more reserved in writing than speech, finding *buck naked* prior to *butt naked* does not conclusively establish the order they arrived into spoken English.

Comment: @NateEldredge, you have your derivations backwards there: ‘buttock’ is a diminutive of ‘butt’; ‘butt’ isn’t a shortening of ‘buttock’. Oddly (though presumably by chance), ‘buttock’ is attested in writing nearly centuries before ‘butt’. There are cognates from older stages of related Germanic languages, though, that indicate that the word was used even in Old English times, but just happened not to be included in any surviving texts earlier than around 1470.

Answer (score 9):

I remembered reading about this subject a few years ago and I found the [source](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/butt.html):

> The standard expression is “buck naked,” and the contemporary “butt naked” is an error that will get you laughed at in some circles. However, it might be just as well if the new form were to triumph. Originally a “buck” was a dandy, a pretentious, overdressed show-off of man. Condescendingly applied in the US to Native Americans and black slaves, it quickly acquired negative connotations. To the historically aware speaker, “buck naked” conjures up stereotypical images of naked “savages” or—worse—slaves laboring naked on plantations. Consider using the alternative expression “stark naked.”

Answer (score 3):

From African American oral history as well as scholarly historical research, “buck naked” refers to a young, black male slave, “a buck,” who was naked during a close arm inspection prior to sale. [A popular imagining of this historical practice can be seen in this still from the movie {Mandingo} (1975) starring Ken Norton. http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/5e/2b/cb9b59aa498b8adc716394aad1a3/ken-norton-mandingo.jpg] (Although there were strict norms governing nakedness and decorum among Whites, the same norms did not apply to enslaved persons.) As commodities, slaves were frequently forced to endure invasive inspections (including of the genitals) to assess their health, sexual prowess, and potential fertility, similar to how we inspect cars today or horses were inspected prior to that. After the outlawing of the international importation of slaves in 1807, (forced) reproduction with other slaves or (master and slave) was the primary means of increasing slave stock. (Black women slaves were also similarly evaluated prior to sale and/or for the owners’ sexual amusement and satisfaction.) This type of inspection was considered critical given the cost of investment. For instance, in Texas, in 1850, a prime field hand aged 18–31 would cost an average of $1,200, or $36,515 in 2014 dollars.http://www.tshaonline.org/handbook/online/articles/yps01

Black male slaves were referred to as ‘bucks,’ akin to young deer. [Enslaved Blacks were considered livestock under chattel slavery.] Native American men were also referred to as “bucks,” both because of the association with buck skins and their being thought savage animals whose traditional habitat was the wild.

Comment: Your formatting (or lack thereof) makes this very difficult to read and understand, but this seems like a lot of supported information on slavery without a lot of backing for the two crucial points: That black male slaves were referred to as “bucks” and that “buck naked” comes from their nudity during these inspections.

Comment: It doesn’t reassure me any that the single (and somewhat extraneous) statement for which you provide a source (“in Texas, in 1850, a prime field hand aged 18—31 would cost an average of $1,200”) is not, strictly speaking, supported by the linked text in _The Handbook of Texas_ which provides that figure as the average cost “during ***the late 1850s***” for “prime male field hands aged eighteen to ***thirty***” (emphasis mine).