# Where did "butt naked" come from?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english

Apparently this question was asked over a decade ago but, the answers given do not address my specific curiosity. Of course, years ago, no one said "butt naked". "Butt" was not a common word - "bottom" and "behind" sufficed in polite company.

I was curious if the change from "buck naked" to "butt naked" was specifically engineered by the media due to racial sensitivities?

To be clear: I have read the hypothesis that the origin of "buck naked" (in AmE) is from naked Native American males - who were often called "bucks". However, in my experience, the change from "buck" to "butt" started in the 1980's.

Yes, the American lexicon had relaxed to include more words that were considered "impolite" - but the fact that male, African American slaves were also called "bucks" made me wonder if the shift was intentionally pushed in media to obliterate the earlier form of the phrase.

Comment: What time period are you referring to when "butt" was not a common word? According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/butt#etymonline_v_18146) the word (in the sense of "buttocks") is attested since 1860. And *buttocks* dates to c. 1300.

Comment: The weight of the conclusion is not borne by the meager premise. 1. Claiming that nobody would have *said* *"butt" naked* sounds a lot like *observer bias.* 2. Never assume malice if ignorance is a sufficient explanation. 3. By the way: I'd compare Spanish *puta*, *pula*, Fr. *putain*, etc. pp. to land on German *puterrot* "red, emberassed", apparently from *Puter, Pute* "turkey", akin to *pussy* if from *put-put*. The corresponding sound change is virtually guaranteed by *bucket* ~ Ger. *Pokal*; *pot* ~ Fr. *bouteille*; *apotheka* ~ *bodega*, etc.—but it is certainly not trivial.

Comment: ***buck** naked* has been [more popular for longer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=butt+naked%2Cbuck+naked&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than ***butt** naked*, but I guess that doesn't prove it's not a euphemism. I always assumed it referred to "near-naked" young male native Indians back in the Wild West days. In Britain we have ***bollock** naked* - but I'm not aware of any euphemistic version of *that* one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct, "buck naked" or "butt naked"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/which-is-correct-buck-naked-or-butt-naked) Also [What is the origin of the phrase "buck naked"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101053/)

Comment: @The Photon - I probably worded that wrong, Yes, the word "butt" was used. (Pork butt, rifle butt) However, it was not a common euphemism for ass.  It was not used in children's TV or movies. Polite company was more expansive - so, it was "bottom" or "behind" unless it was "ass".

Comment: Sorry but,..what is your question in short????

Comment: Again, in what time frame are you talking about? Etymonline indicates the word was found in a written source (that's what they mean by "attested") as a synonym of *buttocks* around 1860. So there was no time in your or my life when it wasn't used with that meaning. Even if your family thought it too vulgar, that doesn't mean that it wasn't common in other social groups.

Comment: And the citation in Gio's answer says that the word has been used with that meaning since the 17th C.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I am not disputing the fact that "butt" was a synonym for "buttocks" in the 19th century.  Folks simply did not use that specific word often in the first three quarters of the 20th century. Not because it would burn their delicate little ears - it simply was not commonly used. Again, if you were being polite, you would say "behind" or "bottom". If you were polite and sophisticated, you would say "derriere".  My family were of a coarser sort and used the word "ass".

Comment: My experience is that it's not just a matter of coarser or more polite, there was a distinction of usage. On a man, if it was small it was a butt and if it was large it was an ass, while on a woman it was the opposite: a large one was a butt but a small one was an ass. And I have no reason to believe (unless you can cite research that shows it) that this usage appeared abruptly in 1975.

Comment: @Oldbag - it is not clear yet what you are looking for. Your personal opinions about usage are fine, but irrelevant from a linguistic perspective.

Comment: @Gio - I haven't posited an opinion. Simply asking if anyone has evidence that the term "butt naked" evolved artificially to become the most used version of the phrase. Specifically, if mass media adopted it to phase-out the older (and more commonly used) "buck naked" - because it might be construed as racist. It's a strange experience, when you've heard something all your life, and suddenly a different form has taken it's place.

Comment: @Oldbag - buck naked does have a racist connotation as MW notes, (at least for those who have that perception). My personal impression is that butt was the original term which, probably by assonance, was changed to buck. Was butt too obscene a term a century  ago ? Probably.

Answer (score 1):

Butt naked is an alternative version of the same phrase buck naked. In some ways, it the more intuitive form: if you are completely naked, your butt is showing. You are, therefore, butt naked.

But English has never claimed to be an intuitive language, and buck naked is an older phrase, so it remains

Comment: Sounds like an eggcorn: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Comment: @alphabet - I suppose that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Green’s Dictionary of Slang suggests that buck in buck-naked can possibly derive, as an alteration, from butt:

[buck-naked](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/eugskya#3ujotwa) (adj.) (also buck, bucked)

> [as naked as a SE buck; ***or ? corruption of butt n.1 (1a) + SE naked]***
>
> ***Butt***; concerning the body.
>
> 1(a) (also butt-end, butties) the buttocks; the posterior; the anus.

> - 1928    [US]    J. Peterkin Scarlet Sister Mary 33: *You ain’ to stand up buck naked like dat.*

[Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/buck-naked-or-butt-naked) suggests that buck-naked is older in usage than butt-naked but that the former could be considered offensive:

> Some think that the original was butt, based on that word having been used to refer to a person’s buttocks since the 17th century, and that buck was a euphemism. Others feel that the buck referred to buckskin (the skin of a male deer, an animal often found in a nude state), or that it came from the word’s sense meaning “a male American Indian or African-American” (this sense of buck is considered offensive).

……..

> Both buck naked and butt naked are of an informal variety of English; you are unlikely to have cause to use either in writing for school, or most types of work. Buck is the older of the twain, but, given the linguistic register in which such words are typically found you should really just choose the one that brings you the most joy.

Comment: Trigger Warning: The sense considered offensive is obviously a *thought terminating cliche* because the exposition fails to consider how it ended up as a slur. Clearly it requires *buck naked* or something like it as the prototype from which *buck* could be formed. The homophone German *Backen* are (butt) cheecks, technically clamp brackets (eg. breaks) or diminutive face cheeks; which is probably related to *back-side* or *bacon*. Now for the trigger, I know only one cultural sphere where ham is officially taboo.

Comment: Where is Green from? Perhaps "buck naked" is an American twist on an older expression used elsewhere. However, if Green is an American, he's talking out of his butt. Buck was used here first.

Comment: @Oldbag / what don’t you publish a dictionary yourself? ELU might se it a a reference.